# Agisot Photoscan Professional to Mesh Lab

Tags: 3d, meshlab

So I have a couple of 3D model files (type .psx) which I created in the Agisoft Photoscan Professional software package.

This is great for observing the model, but not so great when I need to measure it. It was recommended that I use the Mesh Lab software package to do this, but I can't find a way to open the Agisoft files in MeshLab.

**Note:** I do not have access to a computer which can run both software packages.

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to export the models in one of the formats that are supported by MeshLab (like OBJ or PLY)?

PSX seems to be a native project format, so it contains everything, not only the model.